# Tomcat page is not coming up when run from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using tomcat 7 and when I am using this through eclipse as well.

when i am running the tomcat from terminal(using ./startup.sh) it runs the tomcat page with "localhost:8080" but when i try to do it through eclipse it does not start bring up the page.Could any one point what i am missing here.

Thanks

Comment: how do you run tomcat through eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`http://localhost:8080/`in-place of localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can open the index page of tomcat is eclipse just use most parts of Tomcat component and configure it a little differently from using Tomcat only.

What you need to you do is to let eclipse to talk full control of Tomcat.

Here is the step:
(1)Double click the Tomcat server in the 'Servers' view to open the overview of tomcat configuration. You can see the 'Server Locations' in the middle of the page.
[image: Server Locations]

(2)And then selection the second option:'User Tomcat installation(takes control of Tomcat installation)', save. Finally, you can open the index page of tomcat.

But if this panel is disable, you need to do a little more configuration:
Right click the tomcat server in 'Servers' view -->Select Properties-->In the General Tab, press the 'Switch Location' button and Apply. The panel will be unlocked.